# How to fire two asynchro funcs synchronously?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a function:

```
fn = () => {
   fn1(); // call first
   fn2(); // call only when listener is done from fn1
}
```

and these two fns:

```
fn1 = () => {
   const k1 = new Image();
   k1.src = someSrc;
   k1.addEventListener('load', () => some func {});
}
```

My question: What to do to make `fn2` function fire only when `fn1` is called and load event is fired?

```js
const fn = async () => {
   await fn1(); // call first
   await fn2(); // call only when listener is done from fn1
}

const fn1 = async () => {
   const k1 = new Image();
   k1.src = await 'https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/326/326253/corgi-and-terrier-running.jpg';
   await k1.addEventListener('load', async () => await console.log('it should log first'));
}

const fn2 = async () => {
   console.log('then second');
}

fn();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been asked many times, but in case it hasn't: `k1.addEventListener('load', () => {doStuff(); fn2()});`

Comment: @RayToal thanks but this way isnt enough for me in my case (have to do it out of the box, with async/await probably)

Comment: I believe you can use async await.. so make the fn: async fn = () => {await fn1(); await fn2();} and make fn1: async fn1 = () =>{}

Comment: @GlenK async/await is sufficient? without any promises?

Comment: Async/await is not sufficient.You need to wrap the load in a promise.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? You did say you wanted fn2 called after "listener is done from fn1". I assume that means after your "some func" is called. That's the question I answered to the best of my ability. If there is something more specific you need, do rewrite the question and we will be happy to help. Are you saying that fn1 is already complete and you are not allowed to change it?

Comment: @NicholasTower right, I did not see the load events part.. was just thinking that async/await should be enough is f2 is being executed after f1 is done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work with async/await, as mentioned in the comments, then you'll need to create and return a promise:

```
const fn1 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const k1 = new Image();
    k1.src = someSrc;
    k1.addEventListener('load', resolve);
  });
}
```

Then you can await this promise in an async function:

```
const fn = async () => {
  await fn1();
  fn2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
const fn1 = () => {
   const k1 = new Image();
   k1.src = 'https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/326/326253/corgi-and-terrier-running.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(k1);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   k1.addEventListener('load', () => resolve('I am done!'));
  })
}

const fn2 = () => {
   console.log('then second');
}

const fn = async () => {
   const a = await fn1(); // call first
   console.log(a);
   fn2(); // call only when listener is done from fn1
}

fn();
```

Comment: Thank you bratko, regards from poland